# Android Studio gradle sync, try to download jar instead of aar by mistake

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am using Android Studio 1.4 preview 3, gradle plugin 1.3.
Hi, i upload a aar package to bintray jcenter:

https://bintray.com/kevinho/maven/opencore-amr-android/view

And i setup repositories like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

When I try to use it as a dependency,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.hikvh:opencore-amr-android:1.0.0'
}
```

I get following error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not find opencore-amr-android.jar (com.hikvh:opencore-amr-android:1.0.0).   Searched in the following
>   locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/hikvh/opencore-amr-android/1.0.0/opencore-amr-android-1.0.0.jar

My question goes:
Why gradle try to load jar instead aar file by default?
And how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dependency is loading as aar correctly.
Maybe library wasn't released by JCenter yet when you tried to download it.

Let's try to remove gradle cache.
1) Be sure that you have `compile 'com.hikvh:opencore-amr-android:1.0.0'` in your dependencies.
2) From your home directory `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches`
3) From you project root `rm -rf .gradle`
4) Run `gradlew` from project `./gradlew assemble`

Comment: I find it not checked, should i check this? What will happen if i did this?

Comment: @KevinHe it means – work offline, don't load new dependencies. I edited my answer, try to clean gradle cache

Comment: it works！I try to delete all the caches, it just works!

Comment: This does not work reliably. I have two imports of aar files, one works without "@aar", the other one needs "@aar" or it tries to load a jar file.

Answer (score 14):

You need to tell Gradle that you're trying to refer an AAR, not a JAR.

Replace

`compile 'com.hikvh:opencore-amr-android:1.0.0'`

with

```
compile 'com.hikvh:opencore-amr-android:1.0.0@aar'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's redundantly, gradle download aar without problem

Comment: Hi,@jmvk, did your try to add dependency in your build.gradle?compile 'com.hikvh:opencore-amr-android:1.0.0'? Did it work? You can ref my lib: https://bintray.com/kevinho/maven/opencore-amr-android/view , it is indeed a aar package

Comment: Hi Kevin. No, didn't try sorry, wrote the reply while I was on the go.

Comment: This solution worked and its simpler than the other one related to cleaning gradle caches.

Comment: Thank you man, even after 8 years I had to refer back to this answer. It seems explicitly calling the .AAR file always works irrespective of whatever the cache issue might be. Kodus!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was an issue with how Android Studio environment was configured.

When I updated the `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `JDK Location` to a later Java version (`jdk1.8.0_192.jdk` - for me), everything started working.

**NOTICE**: If you follow [Stas Parshin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3252320/stas-parshin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32270982) (thanks for that one!) - there can still be a discrepancy between your shell's `JAVA_HOME` which is used by `./gradlew` and the one configured in your Android Studio.